# How to convert callback code to async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am working with **Mongoose ODM** for **MongoDB** in a node express-based web application which provides its API in a callback fashion. This fashion creates a callback hell to populate documents.

Edit 1: I have added the current working code.

```
User.remove({}, (err) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  let admin = new User({
    email: 'admin@dap.com',
    password: 'dapdap'
  })

  admin.save((err, admin) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err)

    console.info('Success')
    mongoose.disconnect()
  })

})
```

Is there an elegant way to convert the callbacks into async/await fashion in javascript in general? And in mongoose environment?

Comment: any sample code?

Comment: @zabusa I forgot to add the code. I have added it. Please check :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Promise:

```
const userRemovePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.remove({}, (err) => {
      if (err) reject();

      let admin = new User({
        email: 'admin@dap.com',
        password: 'dapdap'
      })

      admin.save((err, admin) => {
        if (err) reject();

        resolve();
      })

    });

});

userRemovePromise.then(function(){  
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to configure mongoose to use bluebird?

`mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`

Then you could get fancy and do:

```
User.remove().then(() => {
    let admin = new User({ ... });

    admin.save().then((admin) => {

    }).catch((err) => {
      //Saving admin error handling
    });
}).catch((err) {
  //User remove error handling
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The same code you wrote above can be written as a promise. From the original docs,

"Mongoose queries are not promises. However, they do have a .then() function for yield and async/await. If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function."

Thus you can use the async await pattern as follows,

```
async function removeUser () {
    // Surround the following call with a try catch
    await User.remove({});
}
```

EDIT:

One answer here says about plugging in blue bird promises. While this is a good approach, it is optional. You can do the same without plugging in your own Promise library.

Answer (score 0):

As mongoose's default promise library mpromise is now deprecated so you can plugin your own promise library to make mongoose's operations work with await/async.

**Mongoose queries are not promises. However, they do have a .then() function for yield and async/await. If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function.**

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird'); bluebird promise
// mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // default js promise - 4x- time slower than bluebird

async function removeUser () {
  try {
    await User.remove({}).exec();
    let admin = new User({
      email: 'admin@dap.com',
      password: 'dapdap'
    })
    await admin.save();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Official Doc: [mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Mongoose returns a Promise as well as providing the regular callback-style pattern. Since `async` functions are syntatic sugar over Promises, you can `await` calls to Mongoose methods.

```
async function clearUsers () {
  try {
    await User.remove({})
    let admin = new User({
      email: 'admin@dap.com',
      password: 'dapdap'
    })
    await admin.save()
    console.info('Success')
    mongoose.disconnect()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Some things to keep in mind:

- `async` functions *always* returns a Promise. If you don't return anything from an `async` function, it will still return a Promise that resolves when execution of that function finishes, but will not resolve with any value.
- `try/catch` in an `async` function works the same as for regular, synchronous code. If *any* function call in the `try` body `throw` or return a Promise that *rejects*, execution stops right on that line and proceeds to the `catch` body.
- Rejected promises "trickle" up the function call chain. This means that the top-most callee can handle errors. See the below example:

This is an anti-pattern that should be avoided unless you absolutely need to handle an error in a specific function, possibly to provide a return value from a different source:

```
async function fn1 () {
  throw new Error("Something went wrong")
}

async function fn2 () {
  try {
    await fn1()
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}

async function fn3 () {
  try {
    await fn2()
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}

async function run () {
  try {
    await fn3()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

The above could rather be implemented like the below and still catch the error, not resulting in a runtime panic/crash:

```
async function fn1 () {
  throw new Error("Something went wrong")
}

function fn2 () {
  return fn1()
}

function fn3 () {
  return fn2()
}

async function run () {
  try {
    await fn3()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

There are *multiple ways* to write the above code that will all be valid, so I recommend that you explore these.

Keeping the above examples in mind, your function `clearUsers()` could then be rewritten to this:

```
async function clearUsers () {
  await User.remove({})
  let admin = new User({
    email: 'admin@dap.com',
    password: 'dapdap'
  })
  await admin.save()
  mongoose.disconnect()
}
```

And then possibly called in two different ways;

*By interacting with the Promise returned directly:*

```
clearUsers()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Success')
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e)
  })
```

*Or from within another async function:*

```
(async function () {
  try {
    await clearUsers()
    console.log('Success')
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})()
```

If *any* function call within the `clearUsers()` function throws, for example `await admin.save()`, execution will stop on that line and return a *rejected* Promise which will be caught in the corresponding `catch` blocks in both variants.

Answer (score -2):

Using Bluebird is a good option to handle callbacks in promises, It makes it easier to understand to an extent.

However I would recommend you to try

[Async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html)

It is built particularly for managing asynchronous nature of javascript.

[This particular function](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) of the library would do exactly what you want.